# Internal styling in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I would have assumed that this would have been easy for me to find but I can't find it anywhere. In HTML you can style all your tags (headers, paragraphs, img, etc.) like this:

```
<style>
  body {background-color: powderblue;}
  h1   {color: blue;}
  p    {color: red;}
</style>
```

How do I do the same in React? I want to reference all `p` tags and some `custom` ones from classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react it would be something like below. you use style prop to apply `inline styles` and in react `background-color` is `backgrounColor`.

To apply same style for all p tags, h1 tags and body you use same .css file and you put all css styles into .css file and the css file has to be imported in parent component so that the style you have in .css file will be applied. Something like below

**app.css**

```
body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}
```

**App.js component**

```
 import "./app.css";//so the styles will be applied to body and all h1 and p tags as global
```

Below are few inline style examples of react
Note: is neither a string nor HTML, It is called JSX, and it is a syntax extension to JavaScript. [Doc here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

```
<body style={{backgroundColor: "powderblue"}}>
   <h1 style={{color: "blue"}}> </h1>
   <p style={{color: "red"}}></p>
 </body>
```

OR

```
render(){
   const style= {colorBlue: "blue", colorRed: "red"};

   return(
      <div>
         <h1 style={{color: style.colorBlue}}> </h1>
         <p style={{color: style.colorRed}}></p>
       </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think about making an outside css page and calling it in. Thanks!

Comment: @tdlanghe You are welcome. Please do upvote as well if the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

ReactJs is just a javascript framework, that "runs" on an HTML page. So, if you want to add those style definitions globally, you can include them in the head section of your master layout page or container page, the one that contains the "root" react component.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
    body {background-color: powderblue;}
    h1   {color: blue;}
    p    {color: red;}
</style>
<!-- your other css and javascript definitions, including probably react -->
</head>
<body>
    <MyReactComponent />
</body>
</html>
```